# Pig Latin String Encryption

Tags: java

I am writing a program that takes a string, splits it into words, converts the words into pig latin, and then returns the result string. I have it working to a certain point.

For example if I enter these words that do not start with a vowel into the program I get:
pig -> igpay 
trash -> rashtay
duck ->  uckday
(for words that do not start with vowels, they have their first letter removed, added to the end of the word along with "ay")

It also works when the word starts with a vowel (just take the word and add "yay" to the end).

For example if I enter these words into the program I get:
eat -> eatyay 
areyay -> areyay
omelet -> omeletyay

Now the issue I am having is if I combine 2 words, one that starts with a vowel and one that doesn't, it prints out both like they both start with vowels.

For example if I enter these words into the program I get:
pig -> pigyay (should be igpay)
eat -> eatyay (correct)

It might be worth mentioning that the methods "isVowel" & "pigLatinEncrypt" are required to have in this program. Please disregard the other methods that are in the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String input, message;
    int ans1, ans2, key;

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1. to decrypt a message\n2. to encrypt a message");
    ans1 = Integer.parseInt(input);

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1. for an entire message reversal encryption\n"
            + "2. for a Pig-Latin encryption\n3. for a simple Caesar style encryption");
    ans2 = Integer.parseInt(input);

    if (ans2 == 3) {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a key for encryption");
        key = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the message to encrypt or decrypt");
    message = input;

    if (ans2 == 1) {
        reverseEncryptandDecrypt(message);
    }

    if (ans2 == 2) {
        String[] words = message.split(" ");
        if (ans1 == 2) {
            boolean isVowel = isVowel(words);
            pigLatinEncrypt(words, isVowel);
        }
        if (ans1 == 1) {
            pigLatinDecrypt(message);
        }
    }

}

public static void reverseEncryptandDecrypt(String message) {

    char[] stringToCharArray = message.toCharArray();

    System.out.print("You entered the message: ");

    for (char c : stringToCharArray) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }

    int i = stringToCharArray.length - 1, j = 0;
    char[] reverse = new char[stringToCharArray.length];

    while (i >= 0) {
        reverse[j] = stringToCharArray[i];
        i--;
        j++;
    }

    System.out.print("\n\nThe result is: ");

    for (char c : reverse) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
    System.out.println();

}

public static void pigLatinEncrypt(String[] words, boolean isVowel) {
    for (String word : words) {
        if (isVowel == true) {
            System.out.print(word + "yay ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(word.substring(1) + word.substring(0, 1) + "ay ");
        }

    }

}


public static boolean isVowel(String[] words) {
    boolean isVowel = false;
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.startsWith("a") || word.startsWith("e") || word.startsWith("i") || word.startsWith("o")
                || word.startsWith("u")) {
            isVowel = true;
        }

    }
    return isVowel;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method:

```
public static void pigLatinEncrypt(String[] words, boolean isVowel)
```

takes an array of words and a *single* `isVowel` boolean.  Thus, if there is more than one word, and some, but not all, of them begin with vowels, there's no way to tell the method that.

You'll need to change the method definition.  Either it should take only one word `String` (simplest), or it needs to take an array of `isVowel` booleans that correspond to the array of word

**Edit:** When I wrote this, I didn't look carefully at the rest of your code.  But the `isVowel` method has the same problem: it takes an array of words, but returns a *single* boolean.  This can't work, for the same reason--if some of the words start with vowels and some don't, what would the method return?

If you can make the `isVowel` method take a single `String` argument, that would be simplest.  Then you'd call it multiple times.  If you want to make `isVowel` return a `boolean[]`, the method would do something like

```
boolean[] result = new boolean[words.length];
```

to create an array of `boolean` that has the same number of elements as `words`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I'm just confused on how to write this program then. I'm supposed to have a return value for my "isVowel" method, but I'm not sure how to turn a returned value into an array for the "pigLatinEncrypt" method.